# Laravel: Mass search and update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Table: Settings

Columns: `id`, `option` and `value`

I was wondering if there is a way to search and update multiple rows in one go?

Something along these lines of:

```
Setting::find(array(
    'option' => 'name',
    'option' => 'address',
    'option' => 'phone'
))->save(array(
    Input::get('name'),
    Input::get('address'),
    Input::get('phone')
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can use the query builder to do this.

```
$updates = array(
    'name' => Input::get('name'),
    'address' => Input::get('address'),
    'phone' => Input::get('phone')
);

DB::table('settings')
        ->where('id', 1)
        ->update($updates);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You just gave me an idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, I was able to achieve the same by adding a custom method into the Settings model, my working code:

**Controller**

```
Setting::massUpdate(array(
            'company_name' => Input::get('company_name'),
            'company_slogan' => Input::get('company_slogan'),
            'company_abn' => Input::get('company_abn'),
            'company_acn' => Input::get('company_acn'),
            'company_address' => Input::get('company_address'),
            'company_phone' => Input::get('company_phone'),
            'company_email' => Input::get('company_email'),
            'money_split' => Input::get('money_split'),
            'fuel_levy' => Input::get('fuel_levy'),
            'booking_cancel_fee' => Input::get('booking_cancel_fee'),
            'booking_hourly_fee' => Input::get('booking_hourly_fee'),
        ));
```

**Model**

```
public static function massUpdate($settings)
    {
        foreach ( $settings as $option => $value )
        {
            $setting = Setting::where('option', '=', $option)->first();
            $setting->value = isset( $value ) ? $value : '';
            $setting->save();
        }
    }
```